# How can I insert a decimal using the Sheets API, regardless of the locale settings?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Using the Sheets API v4, how can I insert a decimal (e.g. `197.99`) while ignoring the locale settings on the spreadsheet which determine the decimal separator?

As an example, if I set the locale to 'Sweden' (which uses commas as their decimal separator), I then set `valueInputOption` to `USER_ENTERED` and insert a value of `197.99`. This ends up displaying as `198.39.00`, when I would expect it to display as `197,99`.

The only thing I can think of would be to read the locale settings on the sheet and reformat my numbers before sending them in, however, this would require me as a developer to maintain the list of locales which use commas as their separators and it doesn't feel correct.

I am hoping there's a way to achieve this via a formatting rule on the cell or similar.

Comment: Could you try passing the value as text and then cast it as number when you retrieve them?

Comment: Unfortunately @AMolina I need it to be formatted appropriately in the spreadsheet as I'm writing the info to the sheet for it to be used by the user directly, not read again as part of my app.

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_patterns) on custom formatting, it shows you how to set it up both in the UI and with the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to 'solve' this by using custom number formatting, so I did end up reading the locale of the spreadsheet and reformatting the numeric values myself.

I'm using Node, so I called `service.spreadsheets.get()`:

```js
service.spreadsheets.get({
    'spreadsheetId': options.event.meta.related_id,
}, function(err, response) {
    if(err) {
        return next(err);
    }

    global.debug.info('Received spreadsheet info', response.data);

    next(null, {'locale': response.data.properties.locale, 'title': response.data.properties.title || '', 'timezone': response.data.properties.timeZone});
});
```

And then I used the results of that locale parameter to reformat my numbers appropriately. I have applied it when the following values are detected:

```js
var comma_locales = ['es_AR', 'hy_AM', 'az_AZ', 'be_BY', 'es_BO', 'pt_BR', 'bg_BG', 'fr_CA', 'es_CL', 'cs_CZ', 'da_DK', 'es_EC', 'fi_FI', 'fr_FR', 'ka_GE', 'de_DE', 'el_GR', 'hu_HU', 'id_ID', 'it_IT', 'kk_KZ', 'lv_LV', 'lt_LT', 'mn_MN', 'nl_NL', 'nb_NO', 'nn_NO', 'es_PY', 'pl_PL', 'pt_PT', 'ro_RO', 'ru_RU', 'sr_RS', 'sk_SK', 'sl_SI', 'eu_ES', 'es_ES', 'sv_SE', 'tr_TR', 'uk_UA', 'es_UY', 'es_VE', 'vi_VN'];
```